# MacOS: Check if boot manager is active

Tags: boot, mac, refind

I have installed `refind` on my `10.14.3` MacOS

```
pkaramol@Panteliss-MacBook-Pro EFI $ pwd
/Volumes/ESP/EFI
panteliskaramolegkos@Panteliss-MacBook-Pro EFI $ ls -lh
total 24
drwxrwxrwx  1 pkaramol  staff   4.0K May 13 17:21 APPLE
drwxrwxrwx  1 pkaramol  staff   4.0K May 20 10:38 refind
drwxrwxrwx  1 pkaramol  staff   4.0K May 20 10:38 tools
```

However when I boot my Mac Book Pro, I never get a prompt like this:

[image]

I know that even now that I only have MacOS installed, I should be getting a similar prompt when the machine boots.

How can I make sure `refind` is indeed my boot manager and if I go and install another OS I will be able to select the OS I want at boot time?

Comment: Did you fix https://superuser.com/questions/1438905/mojave-macos-dual-boot-and-refind-boot-manager yet, or is this really the same question?

Comment: No this is a different (stand alone) question; it asks whether with the `refind` installed I should be prompted with the above screen during boot independently of whether I have dual/multiple boot set up; and if I don't why this is happening.